# Is the intersection of two connected subspaces of a connected topological space is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I think the statement is true that two connected subspaces of a connected topological space is connected, and there are two different situations here to be discussed.

First of all, when the intersection is empty set, do we consider it as connected or not?

For the other situation, if the intersection is not empty, how could I get the conclusion?

Comment: I suppose you mean the union of two connected subspaces?

Comment: What if the space is the real line, and the two connected subspaces are the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$?

Comment: @XuqiangQin Sorry for the confusion here, I missed the intersection on the question part.

Comment: @bof sorry for the confusion, I just corrected the question.

Comment: What if the space is the plane $\mathbb R^2$ and the two connected subspaces are circles intersecting in two points?

Comment: @bof Thanks for the tip. I'm still not sure that if the empty set is connected or not? I think there is a controversy on that one.

Comment: @Luker The empty set is connected. Otherwise by deifnition it would be the union of two nonempty disjoint sets, which is impossible.

Comment: A simple example: $\between$ is the intersection of $($ and $)$.

Answer (score 21):

The empty set is connected (trivially), because we cannot write it as a union of non-empty (!) disjoint open sets..

But the intersection of two connected sets need not be connected at all. Consider $C = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, which is the unit circle (connected) and $D = \{(x,y): (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$, the circle of radius 1 around $(1,0)$, also connected. Their intersection is $\{(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}),(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3})\}$, which is a two point set in the plane, hence disconnected.

Comment: Is it possible to construct an example in $\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: @S717717 no, in the reals connected is the same as order convex (intervals or segments ) and these are closed under intersections.

Answer (score 13):

Consider the intersection of the line segment and the circle in $\mathbb R^2$.